# Use := and = for assignment

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages

I want to know why some programming languages use := and some use = for assignment?
What are some of the logical difference between them?

Comment: Some languages, e.g. [AHK](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autohotkey/info), use _both_ of these operators for assignment, with different semantics.

Answer (score 2):

A language will (typically) need both an assignment operator and a compare operator. For humans an equal sign `=` can be read as both depending on context but compilers need a different syntax for those two to avoid  ambiguity.

Language A could have the syntax

```
a = b    // assignment
a == b   // comparison
```

and language B could have the syntax

```
a := b   // assignment
a = b    // comparison
```

and yet another language could completely avoid the `=` sign

```
mov a, b // assignment
cmp a, b // comparison
```

It doesn't really matter.
The language designer can choose whatever they prefer as long as a compiler/interpreter is able to parse the syntax.